# Compact Database VBA for an .mdb that utilizes a .mdw security file

Tags: ms-access

The below code works great when you call an unsecured database from another database. But I am trying to compact an .mdb in Office 2013 that has user-level security (.mdw).

If I try the below code with an .mdb with .mdw and try and compact the open database I get error 3045, file in use.

If I try the below code with an .mdb with .mdw and try and compact a different database I get error 3033, do not have necessary permissions.

If anyone has a solution that would be wonderful. Thank you in advance!

```
Public Function CompactAndRepairAccessDB()

    Dim Acc As Object
    Set Acc = CreateObject("access.application")

    Dim dbPath As String, dbPathX As String
    dbPath = "\\servername\database.mdb"
    dbPathX = "\\servername\databaseTEMP.mdb"

    Acc.DBEngine.CompactDatabase dbPath, dbPathX
    Acc.Quit
    Set Acc = Nothing
    Kill dbPath
    Name dbPathX As dbPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-compactdatabase-method-dao?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(dao360.chm1052936);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), the CompactDatabase method takes a password as the last parameter.

`CompactDatabase(SrcName, DstName, DstLocale, Options, password)`

This would be the `admin` password for the database if there are multiple users.

BTW, you cannot compact the current database from code. You *can* create a small Access database to compact your other databases with though.